# Custom Domain for Azure Cloud Service

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have my sample website here on Azure

http://1f1e8bdb96d34b769ee79b2d23d2b167.cloudapp.net/

I want to map it to my customer domain.

www.api.tplex.com

How can I do it with subdomain?

Answer (score 3):

See this: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/

Make sure that you've actually set up the CNAME record, it makes a check to see if it points to the site URL.

Comment: I have not azure website I have website hosted on azure hosted service in webrole

Comment: It's about the same process, read this: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/

Answer (score 2):

Based on the GUID in the URL, that looks like a staging site that just got a new build deployed to it. You must have a DNS (http://your-app-name.cloudapp.net) set up for the main cloud service app, right? Create a CNAME record at your registrar's website where you registered your domain name and point it to this http://your-app-name.cloudapp.net URL.

Also, in case you weren't aware of it already, use [VIP swapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee517253.aspx) technique to deploy builds from stage to production, i.e. from http://some-guid.cloudapp.net/ to http://your-app-name.cloudapp.net/